Azure AD B2C with SAML and skip the login page
I have a custom policy configured on my Portal application with a SAML protocol to authenticate the user on another application(QlikSense).
If I try to open the URL https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/generic/login?EntityId=https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/idp&RelayState=https://<domain>/<PORTAL> it shows a login page.
I can see on SAML-tracer that after login the authentication works. Now I would like to make this authentication after the user login on Portal application without the login page.
Is there any way to accomplish this on Azure AD B2C without showing the login page using an access token?
I can't use this login page on my application because I already use another custom policy on Portal application using OIDC. I can't use OIDC to make this integration because the other application(QlikSense) doesn't work with OIDC.
MSAL doesn't work with SAML, so I will need to implement all the behavior of login page.

Near your EntityID my urls are different  https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com//generic/login?EntityId=&RelayState=   - however, I have never seen a definitive answer on what is correct.

You may be able to achieve SSO with the session providers.
These are:

DefaultSSOSessionProvider
ExternalLoginSSOSessionProvider

You could create your own session provider that combines them.
Both these allow extra claims to be written to the provider.
Note that the SamlSSOSessionProvider does not allow any extra claims to be added.

There are no examples combining them?
